# Easy navigation between meta and "parent" site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0

Currently you have to scroll all the way down and select **parent site** or **meta** to switch between the two sites.

I think the best UI would be a tab style interface on the top left. If you look at the beta of WebApps, you will notice that there is unused space on the top left which has a blue background. If there were two large tabs there: "WebApps" and "Meta", it would make switching between the sites much easier.

Right now I use two different bookmarks for both sites since switching between the two isn't very easy. Additionally, you could have little indicators next to each one (similar to the mail icon currently in use) so that you know if you have any notifications waiting for you in the other site, without having to visit it explicitly.

Comment: Absolutely agree.  People (ok...me) expect the link to be in the footer bar with the other sites as we are used to.  The other day I had a question all typed up saying there was no way to get from meta.newsite to newsite.  I tried a search of the source html for kicks and giggles and that's the only reason I know the parent site link is there.  It is especially confusing given that the link for meta with the colored icon goes to meta.sitename, not here.  Once you get to meta, you expect to use a similar process to return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, there is now a link at the top left to switch between meta and parent:

http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/2917/metaparentnav.png

Comment: @Kyle, can you hard refresh?

Comment: @Jin OK that works, sorry, false alarm

Comment: I didn't see it on the meta site at first, after Shift-F5ing, I now see it though. Thanks for the feature @Jeff!

Answer (score 1):

There's now a banner with a link across the top of the site.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but it doesn't fit well with the theme. I think it's great temporarily at first to get users acquainted. I'm looking for something more permanent. Additionally, there's no banner on the meta site.

Answer (score 0):

Or just keep them open on two tabs?

Answer (score 0):

How about another link (alongside the search box): "Return to <*Name*>"