# Link back to Stack Exchange property from its Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, meta

Sometimes I have this very strange type of laziness where I'll hunt for a link to where I want to go rather than just typing it into the address bar.  Just now, I couldn't find a link from [meta.webapps.stackexchange.com](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com) back to [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com).

I think it makes sense to link back to the main site in case someone lands on the Meta site from a Google search and doesn't understand what everyone's talking about.

Edit:  Of course, I just now found the "parent site" link at the very bottom.  Maybe it should be more prominent?

Comment: Related request for easier navigation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55551/easy-navigation-between-meta-and-parent-site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a meta link at the top of the page on all sites. (link will say "parent" if you are on the meta already)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed with the rollout of the network-wide banner.

Answer (score 0):

It took this question for me to spot the "parent site" link.

Shouldn't that link be

1. At the the top of the page, and
2. Labelled with the name of the site?

As it stands it is not really discoverable.