# Why doesn't reputation from Stack Overflow "trickle" to Meta?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should reputation from SO carry over to Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/should-reputation-from-so-carry-over-to-meta)

Stack Overflow and Meta seem like the same site; shouldn't they have the same karma or reputation?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of this question.... at all.

Comment: I don't know the exact reasons why the new SE sites work this way but I would suggest reading this blog post.  It may be of some help when posting further questions. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: @waffles: That's a good point.  I must be too used to using a Q&A site. :)  Until/unless the OP clarifies the question, however, it still seems to be a duplicate: I only answered because I couldn't find a duplicate and wanted to help Tyler understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's not how Meta (this site) has worked traditionally and there are overwhelming reasons to keep it this way.

Meta used to cover all 3 sites: SO, SF, and SU; however, you'll notice [meta.SF](https://meta.serverfault.com/) and [meta.SU](https://meta.superuser.com/) are like the new SE meta sites (in particular, they share rep with the parent site).  Even dropping out SF and SU questions, Meta still covers much more than SO, such as the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer), is the main site to report bugs in the SE engine, and still provides all-SE-encompassing discussion & questions in a multitude of various ways.

In order to make Meta follow the other metas, we'd need someone to sort through all the questions and create yet *another* site to host the non-SO bits (or re-use meta.stackexchange.com, but then the content from the SE 1 meta has to go somewhere, and I doubt merging is a good idea—yet).  This would wreak major havoc.

This has been proposed before, but I can't find the link after well exceeding my search patience. :)

Comment: The only reference I can find is on the blog here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/

Comment: Is this the question you are trying to find  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/rep-transfer-from-meta

Comment: @Barry: Definitely useful, but not what I remember reading, which was more along the lines of why Meta is useful without being restricted to SO-only.  IMHO, this is one of the primary ways the SE engine fails at dicussion: we can't find things like this when we need it.  Though, at least, in this particular case, nothing short of a hand-sorted hierarchy is terribly good at it.

Comment: Ok found loads of links about this so here they are:

1. http://bit.ly/cJ8296  
2. http://bit.ly/d51urd   
3. http://bit.ly/9UVTWa   
4. http://bit.ly/ax90tI

Comment: +1 I agree with this. sorry about deleting your comment on my now deleted answer ... I should not have done that, its getting late here and I slipped.

Comment: @waffles: I overreacted as well.  It's not a big issue overall, and it was more that it happened twice in quick succession that got to me.  (I'm still not positive I interpreted the OP correctly here or in the deleted comment on the question; needs OP clarification.)

Comment: except that this is meta.STACKOVERFLOW.com. Understood that it is the center of all sites.