# What happened to the "parent" link in the navigation bar on meta sites?

Tags: support, navigation

I was about to ask for a link on meta sites, similar to the "meta" link on normal SE sites, that would let us navigate back to the parent site. However, it's [already been requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55551/easy-navigation-between-meta-and-parent-site), and apparently completed. But I don't see this link — where did it go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [**main**](https://stackoverflow.com/), between [**blog**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) and [**about**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) at the top of the page.

[image: Screenshot of links at the top of Meta Stack Overflow]

This is placed at the same location on Meta Stack Overflow as the [**meta**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) link is on Stack Overflow.

[image: Screenshot of links at the top of Stack Overflow]

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: But no, it's not in the same place — Meta has an "about" link there.

Comment: I just added some screenshots to clarify.  :)

Comment: I don't see the "about" link on SO, so "main" is in the same place of "blog".

Comment: Huh, that *is* weird that you and I see different things at the top of SO.

Comment: You see different things in the top bar depending on your reputation. And unlike the other per-site metas, this one (Meta.SO) does *not* share reputation with its parent or main site. At higher rep levels, things like "review" and "tools" start to be added, replacing some of the links that were previously visible, like "about". @jtbandes