# How do I navigate out of meta?

Tags: support, per-site-meta

Are there any links from meta sites to the parent sites, for example from [meta.travel.stackexchange](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/) to [travel.stackexchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) ? Or is meta the Hotel California of Stack Exchange?

Comment: What do you mean with "other sites" and "away from Meta"?

Comment: @mods -- add to [meta-tag:faq]?

Comment: "You can check out any time you like, but you can never leave!"

Comment: [It's not just moving between the sites, either, logging out is a problem for some](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3436/where-is-the-logout-link-on-super-user/3437#3437).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happened to the "parent" link in the navigation bar on meta sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101541/what-happened-to-the-parent-link-in-the-navigation-bar-on-meta-sites)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes.  Click on `main` in the top corner of the site.

[image: MAIN!]

And the other way:

[image: META!]

Comment: Oh sure, beat me both in timing and content.  Hmph! ;-)

Comment: Doh! I never used those links, instead using other links from parent to meta that are more one-way.